# XML parsing Jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

I have an XML file which has four `<resultGroups>` tag:

```
<resultGroups> 
    <subGroups>
        <results> </results>
        <results> </results>
    </subGroups>
    <name> </name>
</resultGroups>
```

each `<resultGroup>` has several `<subGroups>` and each `<subGroups>` has several `<result>` tag.

I want to get the no of "results" tag in each subgroups, each resultGroups etc...

How can i do that using jQuery...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$xml = $(xmlString);
$('resultGroups', $xml).each(function() {
    $('subGroups', this).each(function() {
        var count = $('results', this).length;
        // do whatever
    });
});
```

Comment: thnk u for tht.....

If u don't mind can u just give me different approaches or methods possible on an XMl using jquery???

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? You can do any traversing you want, get attributes, set attributes... just read up on the jQuery documentation.