# XML parsing with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

```
<resultGroups> 
    <subGroups>
        <results> </results>
        <name></name>
    </subGroups>
    <subGroups>
        <results> </results>
        <name></name>
    </subGroups>    
    <name>myname</name>
</resultGroups>
<resultGroups> 
    <subGroups>
        <results> </results>
        <results> </results>
        <name></name>
    </subGroups>
    <subGroups>
        <results> </results>
        <results> </results>
        <name></name>
    </subGroups>    
    <name>othername</name>
</resultGroups>
```

how can i select the name tag of first resultGroup only using jquery???

Comment: @Jasim: Why do you keep posting the same question over and over again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980413/xml-parsing-in-jquery - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985500/xml-parsing-jquery? What about reading the documentation to the part of jQuery that is *always* used in the answers to these questions?

Comment: Have you considered marking the answers as answered if it fits your need? or provide a comment if you need any further assistance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "result.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(data){
        // Parsing happens here

    }
 });
```

To parse the document we have two main functions available "each" and "find". The function "each" will loop over all the tags with a specific name, the function "find" will search for a certain tag.

```
$(data).find("resultGroup").each(function() {
    alert("found a resultGroup");
});


$(data).find("resultGroup").each(function() {
        alert($(this).find("subgroups").text());
});


$(data).find("subgroups").each(function() {
        alert($(this).attr("result"));
});
```

Comment: Just to make a note i haven't tested this code, just wrote it out, so you might need to tweak it a little to get the right results :) but it should give you a good basis to understand the answer,

Answer (score 0):

```
$('resultGroup subGroups name')[0]
```

If you want to be more specific, you could split the selection and fetch the first array index for each:

```
$('name', $('subGroups', $('resultGroup')[0])[0])
```

... I think.